# If $\sum (a_n)^2$ converges and $\sum (b_n)^2$ converges, does $\sum \frac{a_n+b_n}n$ converge absolutely?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've got to the point that I know that it converges, but I'm stuck on proving that it converges absolutely, could someone help?
Applying Cauchy-Schwarz, I got
\begin{align*}
\Big(\sum_n \frac{a_n+b_n}n\Big)^2 
&\leqslant\Big(\sum_n {a_n}^2+2\sqrt{\sum_n{a_n}^2\sum_n{b_n}^2}+\sum_n{b_n}^2\Big)\sum_n\frac 1{n^2},
\end{align*}
But how do I prove that this converges absolutely?

Comment: This is a follow-up to: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3583154/631742 The RHS converges because $\sum_n a_n^2$, $\sum_n b _n^2$ and $\sum_n 1/n^2$ all converge

Comment: Note that $(a_n+b_n)^2 \le 2(a_n^2+b_n^2)$.

Comment: Replace $a_n$ with $|a_n|$ and $b_n$ with $|b_n|$ and note the same bound still holds